# Inner Join 2 array object en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, array, objeto, join, inner

se que esto ya esta en el foro pero ninguna respuesta me a dado resultado, quiero hacer un inner join con dos array object:

```
const marca = [
    { idMarca: 1, nombre: 'Nissan' },
    { idMarca: 2, nombre: 'Honda' },
    { idMarca: 3, nombre: 'Toyota' }
];

const auto = [
    { idAuto: 02, color: rojo,  idMarca: 2, anioFab: 2019 },
    { idAuto: 10, color: azul,  idMarca: 1, anioFab: 2016 },
    { idAuto: 15, color: negro, idMarca: 1, anioFab: 2020 },
    { idAuto: 45, color: azul,  idMarca: 2, anioFab: 2021 },
    { idAuto: 60, color: blanco, idMarca: 3, anioFab: 2019 }
];
```

RESULTADO

```
const resultado = [
    { idAuto: 02, color: rojo,  nombreMarca: 'Honda'  anioFab: 2019 },
    { idAuto: 10, color: azul,  nombreMarca: 'Nissan' anioFab: 2016 },
    { idAuto: 15, color: negro, nombreMarca: 'Nissan' anioFab: 2020 },
    { idAuto: 45, color: azul,  nombreMarca: 'Honda'  anioFab: 2021 },
    { idAuto: 60, color: blanco, nombreMarca: 'Totota' anioFab: 2019 }
];
```

Comment: cual es el codigo completo que usas para tratar de hacerlo?

Answer (score 1):

Creo que no es muy complicado, te propongo una solución:

He llamado aut en lugar de auto a cada objeto de la iteración del map porque tu objeto de autos lo has llamado `auto`, considera nombrarlo en plural, lo mismo para marca (marcas), por lo que he llamado a cada marca simplemente `m` en el forEach, algo no recomendable.

#### NOTAS

1. Por si no te llevas muy bien con las interfaces funcionales, lo que hace map es crear un nuevo array del mismo tamaño que el que iteras, pero con elementos nuevos, típicamente los originales transformados de alguna manera.
2. El operador ... copia las propiedades de un objeto dentro de otro que se esté construyendo (incluyendo el idMarca, por eso luego uso delete).

```js
const auto = [
    { idAuto: 02, color: "rojo",  idMarca: 2, anioFab: 2019 },
    { idAuto: 10, color: "azul",  idMarca: 1, anioFab: 2016 },
    { idAuto: 15, color: "negro", idMarca: 1, anioFab: 2020 },
    { idAuto: 45, color: "azul",  idMarca: 2, anioFab: 2021 }
]

const marca = [
    { idMarca: 1, nombre: 'Nissan' },
    { idMarca: 2, nombre: 'Honda' },
    { idMarca: 3, nombre: 'Toyota' }
];


// Primero mapea cada id a su nombre de marca.
const nombresPorId = {}
marca.forEach(m => nombresPorId[m.idMarca] = m.nombre )


// Luego construye el array aplicando una transformación a 
// cada uno de los elementos de auto
const autosConNombresMarcas = auto.map(aut => {
    const nuevo = {
        ...aut, // Todo lo que tenía el auto
        nombreMarca: nombresPorId[aut.idMarca]
    }
    // Borrar idMarca en el nuevo.
    delete nuevo.idMarca
    return nuevo
})

console.log(autosConNombresMarcas)
```

Comment: Buenas noches, me devuelve undefined

Comment: @NicholasSteveEscalanteOliva acabo de comprobarlo, te lo he puesto en modo snippet para que puedas ejecutarlo directamente. No hay ninguna razón por la que pudiera crear un undefined, aparentemente.

Comment: Claro que si, tienes toda la razón. Muchas gracias.

Comment: @NicholasSteveEscalanteOliva me alegro que te haya sido de ayuda. Considera aceptar esta respuesta.